# How to use Kivy allow_stretch?

Tags: python, kivy

Kivy allow_stretch function doesn't work.
This is my code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
GridLayout:
    cols: 3
    Image:
        source: "images/cake.jpeg"
        allow_stretch: False
    Image:
        source: "images/cake.jpeg"
        allow_stretch: True
"""


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


TestApp().run()
```

I wish the pictures will be different, but they look same.
[It looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dHrs.jpg) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dHrs.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set your image size.  They may be too big

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 3
    Image:
        source: "images/cake.jpeg"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 200
        allow_stretch: False
    Image:
        source: "images/cake.jpeg"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 200
        allow_stretch: True
```